# ORA-00936: Missing Expression Error Code

Tags: sql, oracle

New here and was wondering if anyone can shed some light into this `ORA-00936` error with my SQL Query.

```
select Count(Auftragsnr) as Open_Orders
from wa_kopf
where convert(varchar(4), Aender_Datum, 104) = convert(varchar(4), getdate(), 104)
and zustand < (60);
```

Get the following error:

> 14:47:37  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 936, SQL
>   State: 42000]  ORA-00936: Missing Expression

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

JRidge

Comment: Looks like you use `sql-server`  (`convert(varchar(4), Aender_Datum, 104)`) syntax in a `oracle` DB.

Comment: Using DbVisulizer to run my scripts and the server database is :  
Oracle
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
Oracle JDBC driver
11.1.0.7.0-Production

Comment: There is no `convert` in Oracle. Please read the manual

Comment: Well, there is [an Oracle convert function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions034.htm), but it's nothing to do with [the SQL Server convert function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) whose syntax you're using. `get_date()` isn't Oracle, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [SQL Server syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), which won't work with an Oracle database. You seem to be trying to format a date as `dd.mm.yyyy` (but in a 4-character string, somehow?). There is no `getdate` function in Oracle either, but it does have [`sysdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions191.htm) instead.

So the Oracle equivalent for what I think you're trying to do would be:

```
where to_char(Aender_Datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy') = to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

But that would just mean you're comparing dates as string, which isn't generally a good idea. If you're looking for any value from today you could use [the `trunc()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm), which strips the time portion from a date by default; if your column is only representing a date and the time is always midnight then you can do:

```
where Aender_Datum = trunc(sysdate)
```

If your column has varying times then you could truncate that as well:

```
where trunc(Aender_Datum) = trunc(sysdate)
```

... but that can have a performance impact if the column is indexed, and an alternative is to use a range comparison:

```
where Aender_Datum >= trunc(sysdate)
and Aender_Datum  < trunc(sysdate) + 1
```